# ms access, append query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

i have 2 tables in ms access 2010.
Is posible to make something like:??

I have insert query in first table, and i need to insert some data into second table only if field value in first table in specificed row is == 'specificed value',

I googled, and i found append querys. but i cant create something like that.
Can someone help me, is it possible?, is it better to do whole base in mysql?

for example;

insert into table1 (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (1,2,3);
something like trigger-> after insert & if(table1.field2 = 2);
insert into table2 (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (1,2,3 from first table)

i solved half problem with  data macro.
but now i have combo box with 20 posible checkbox.
and i need to do something under condition, if specific combobox is selected.

i tryed next:
for example if target checkbox is on first place

```
if [combobox].Value(0)
if [combobox].Value(1)
if [combobox].Column(0)
if [combobox].Column(1)

[combobox].Column(1) = name of checkbox option

isempty has no sence here,

but i cant test it if checkbox is checked.
```

ass a matter of a fact, i have combo checkbox. multivalued field.

Comment: Can you specify simple 1 example of how you want insert query?? Your description in question looks ok but example will help more to get exact idea that what you want.

Comment: Basically it depends on your knowledge. Are you familiar with Software Development and so on? Then, maybe MySQL it's a better option. Otherwise, I would say you have to stay with ms access. About your question, I think it can be done by creating a Macro (in which, you can concatenate queries, and have some values parameterized).

Comment: I have experience in PHP/cake/mysql. and now i need to do some changes in ms access data base. it looks it would be better to do whole base in mysql instead repair this one.

Comment: Yes, you could do what you describe using an After insert [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx). Give that a try and then [edit] your question with details of your attempt if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: Data macros cannot process multi-valued or attachment data-types.
From here: http://www.365advisor.com/ArticleContenta14b8953b11bec36